# How to process custom tags in a string and record information about formatting

Tags: regex, algorithm, scala, parsing

I'm given a string in the following format:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor <a>Hello <b>Nested</b> World</a> sit amet, consectetur
```

I then parse the tags using regular expressions and get an array of all matches, in this case:

```
val text = "..."
val listOfRegexes = List[Regex](...)
val allMatches = listOfRegexes
    .flatmap(
      r => r
            .findAllMatchIn(text)
            .toList
            .map(m => (m.start, m.end, "..."))
    )

println(allMatches) // [(18, 49, "a"), (27, 39, "b")]
```

The end goal is to remove the tags from the string:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor Hello Nested World sit amet, consectetur
```

And create a list of tuples / objects describing the formatting, in this case it should look like this:

```
[(18, 35, "a"), (24, 29, "b")]
```

**Notice** the indexes have shifted because the tags have been removed

How should I approach writing this algorithm?

Comment: Please provide some piece of code that you tried

Comment: I only managed to sort out the list of matches of tags. Currently trying to figure out how to work with them and the original string. Removing the tags is the easy bit, but I can't figure out how to add formatting information since the indexes are shifting (because the tags are being removed)

Comment: More context is needed. How do you "get an array of all matches"? Show us "the easy bit". Perhaps it's too easy and taking you down the wrong path.

Comment: @jwvh I've updated my question to show how I obtain the matches. Sorry it wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's one way to go about it.

We'll start by locating all the tags in the raw text.

```
val text =
  "Lorem ipsum dolor <a>Hello <b>Nested</b> World</a> sit amet, consectetur"

val tags = "<([^>]+)>".r.findAllMatchIn(text)
                      .map(m => (m.start,m.end-m.start,m.group(1)))
                      .toList
//tags: List[(Int, Int, String)] = List((18,3,a), (27,3,b), (36,4,/b), (46,4,/a))
```

Now that we have all tag locations and lengths, in order, we can clean up the text.

```
val cleanTxt = tags.foldLeft((text,0)){
                 case ((str,acc),(x,len,_)) => (str.patch(x-acc,"",len),acc+len)
               }._1
//cleanTxt: String = Lorem ipsum dolor Hello Nested World sit amet, consectetur
```

It's a little trickier to pair up the tag start/end locations, adjusted for their respective locations in the clean text string.

```
val cleanTags = tags.foldLeft((List.empty[(Int,String)],0)){
                  case ((lst,acc),(x,l,n))=> ((x-acc,n)::lst,acc+l)
                }._1.reverse
//cleanTags: List[(Int, String)] = List((18,a), (24,b), (30,/b), (36,/a))

def pairTags(ts  :Vector[(Int,String)]
            ,acc :List[(Int,Int,String)] = List()
            ) :List[(Int,Int,String)] =
  if (ts.isEmpty) acc.reverse
  else {
    val hd = ts.head
    val matchX = ts.lastIndexWhere(_._2 == "/" + hd._2)
    assert(matchX > 0, "bad tag collection")
    pairTags(ts.tail.patch(matchX-1,Vector(),1)
            ,(hd._1,ts(matchX)._1,hd._2) :: acc)
  }

pairTags(cleanTags.toVector)
//res0: List[(Int, Int, String)] = List((18,36,a), (24,30,b))
```

Note that these are the "from" (inclusive) and "until" (exclusive) index locations for each text span.

Comment: You were right about the "wrong path". Instead of finding content matches, you matched the start and end of each tag, clever.
Thank you, works perfectly.